# when I build apk, it generates a apk but 'with 0 build variants' on Android Studio. And it's broken apk

Tags: android, gradle, apk

When I build apk, it shows with 0 build variants. It generates apk but it's broken and can't install. Is there anybody who experience this issue?`

It shows,

```
APK(s) generated successfully for module 'MY_APP.app' with 0 build variants:
```

And the apk file isn't not installable. it's broken.

Even the old branch that I was able to build correctly, now it's not working. (I haven't changed anything.)

Is there anybody who has suffered this issue?

Comment: `isn't not installable. it's broken` is not very specific. Please try to install the APK files using `adb install` and post the error message.

Comment: Have you found a solution?  I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky it was gradle problem. Try to change gradle version.